# Expected value of invariant distribution associated to a random Markov matrix

Tags: random-variables, markov-chains, random-matrices

Let $\Pi$ a random Markov matrix with dimension $m \times m$, that is, its elements are $\Pi_{ij} \in (0,1)$ and its rows sum to one. The rows are independent random variables, i.e. we can write
$$\Pi = \begin{bmatrix} \Pi_1 \\ \vdots \\ \Pi_m \end{bmatrix}$$
and each row vector $\Pi_i$ is taken at random with a Dirichlet distribution with concentration parameters $(\alpha_{i1},\dots,\alpha_{im})$. We know that for a nonrandom Markov matrix, if it has an invariant distribution, then
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pi^n = 1\pi
\end{equation}
where $\pi$ is the invariant distribution and $1$ a column vector of ones. I am interested in the invariant distribution associated to my *random* Markov matrix. In particular, can we say something about $\mathbb{E}[\log(\pi^{(n)})]$ or $\mathbb{E}[\pi^{(n)}]$, for an element $n \in \{1,\dots,m\}$ of the invariant distribution?

**Added**

In the $2 \times 2$ case, if
$$\Pi = \begin{bmatrix} 1-\Pi_1 & \Pi_1 \\ \Pi_2 & 1-\Pi_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
then
$$ \pi = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\Pi_2}{\Pi_1+\Pi_2} \\ \frac{\Pi_1}{\Pi_1+\Pi_2} \end{bmatrix}$$
and for instance
$$\mathbb{E}[\log(\pi^{(1)})] = \mathbb{E}[\log(\Pi_2)] - \mathbb{E}[\log(\Pi_1+\Pi_2)]$$
and the solution follows since the marginal distributions are Beta and $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ are independent. How would this generalize to $m > 2$?

Comment: this random variable takes its values in $M_m(\mathbb{R})$, is that what you mean?

Comment: I added some details to a particular case that might illustrate it better

Comment: Is this matrix log or elementwise log?

Comment: So basically given a random Markov chain on a fixed finite state space, you want to know something about the typical invariant distribution you get? This seems rather sensitive to the distribution of the entries.

Comment: Correct. I assume a distribution for the entries too (see update)

Comment: Try to do the explicit calculation in the 2x2 case to see if anything happens?

Comment: Yes, I added now the details for that.